# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in Angular 7 and rxjx

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I have recently upgraded my angular 2 app to angular 7. One of the challenges that I had was the `user.service.ts` where I have `isAuthentiated` method is. Basically, this method is passed into the `auth.guard.ts` so that I can direct users if their username is not on my list.

User Service retrieves the users then isAuthenticated checks the users. Auth guard is checking the user. If the user is in the list, grant access, otherwise navigate them to a certain website.

`user.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        const body = res;
        return body || { };
    }

    ... other methods

    isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users').pipe(
            map(this.extractData),
            map(res => !!res.length)
        );
    }
}
```

And my `auth.guard.ts` is:

```
import { UserService } from './../_services/user.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private alertifyService: AlertifyService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.userService.isAuthenticated().pipe(map(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/authentication/get-jhed']);
        this.alertifyService.error('You need to be authenticated to access this area');
        return false;
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

This code returns the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I tried `res[0].length` I didn't receive the error but nothing happened this time.

I am able to solve this issue using `Http` as below:

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users').pipe(
        map(res => res.json()),
        map(res => !!res.length)
    );
}
```

Please note that I use `Http` in here, NOT `HttpClient`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems that the issue is on this line `map(res => !!res.length)`. What exactly are you expecting in the `response`

Comment: Did you migrate from Http to HttpClient at the same time? HttpClient returns other response. I mean it indicates by default for a body not a whole response object.

Comment: You're able to change that behaviour by passing `{ observe: 'response' }` object as options (second param) to `http.get()` method.

Comment: @Magos, I am able to solve the issue with `Http` but not with `HttpClient`. Please see the updated question for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient` by default indicates response body not a whole response object. If you migrate from `Http` to `HttpClient` at the same time - to be compatibile with the previous way - use options object to return whole response in callback.

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'users', { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        map(res => !!res.length)
    );
}
```